# How can I ensure a shared, corporate device never prompts for user sign-in?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, apple-id, guided-access

- We are using supervised devices
- Airwatch is our MDM solution
- Devices are being used sparingly with Guided Access enabled to allow use of one app only
- Some devices use Facetime as above mentioned app, which requires AppleID sign-in

In the past, during critical situations, a device would not allow use until the user signed in. Our end-users do not have access to the shared AppleIDs. Note this was also on devices that were not yet supervised.

What I've done so far..

- All the devices are having ABM purchased apps assigned to them. (This has its own set of problems...)
- For Facetime, I've logged into Facetime only using a shared AppleID and enabled Guided Access
- I have been able to push updates to supervised devices without them being signed in. They have not asked for an AppleID. Yet.

I am still concerned a supervised device will want to update an app or update its iOS on its own and ask for a user sign-in. **That cannot happen in this environment.**

Comment: For corporate devices, there is a way of blocking ios updates. see:  https://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/blog/Modern-Mobility/IT-can-block-iOS-updates-in-iOS-113-finally

Comment: I thought corporate machines no longer require an apple id.